# Is there command like `seq`, that performs full bash-like brace expansion to stdout?

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

In Bash it is often convenient to use brace expansion to nested directory trees, e.g.

```
mkdir -p {foo,bar}/baz{0..9}
```

This works until the expansion is too big for a single ARGV array. A convenient alternative would be `command-x`, which is like `seq` but accepts the same brace expansions as bash, e.g.

```
command-x "{a..z}/{a..z}/{a..z}" | xargs mkdir -p
command-x "{a..z}/{a..z}/{a..z}" | parallel -m mkdir -p
```

Before I reinvent a wheel does `command-x` exist?

The closest I've found so far are implementations as libraries (e.g. https://pypi.org/project/bracex/, https://pypi.org/project/braceexpand/, https://github.com/micromatch/braces). If nothing turns up I may offer a CLI interface to one of the Python ones.

Comment: Note that when not given `-0` or `-d`, `xargs` has some unintuitive behavior -- it tries to parse backslashes, quotes, etc. in a shell-like manner, and splits on unquoted spaces (not just newlines). Thus even when your input is line-oriented, `xargs -d $'\n'` is more correct than just `xargs`. By contrast, if you want compatibility with BSD xargs as well, just use `-0` and NUL-delimit input. See also [BashPitfalls #56](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Using_xargs_without_-0).

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of `-0`, but didn't want to complicate the question. In retrospect I should have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "needs to fit in argv" limitation only applies to external commands, not to shell builtins.

Thus, the shell builtin `printf` is suited to purpose:

```
printf '%s\n' {a..z}/{a..z}/{a..z} | xargs -d $'\n' mkdir -p --
```

...or, better, use `printf '%s\0'` and `xargs -0` to pass through all possible arguments (and all possible filenames), a set which includes content with literal newlines.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm curious what memory consumption that causes - does it stream the expansion, or perform a large allocation to store it all at once? Experimenting now.

Comment: I strongly suspect that it stores it all at once, but your experiment will be more certain.

Comment: Bash (5.0.17) allocates all at once. On my laptop `(printf '%s\n' {a..z}/{a..z}/{a..z}/{a..z}) | wc -l` outputs 456976 which is 26^4. but `(printf '%s\n' {a..z}/{a..z}/{a..z}/{a..z}/{a..z})` is killed before it completes.